# df.explode() not helping to unpack the column values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My intention is to unpack/explode multiple columns in pandas. My dataframe looks like this:

```
cols = ['name','first', 'second']
data = {'name':['image1','image2'],
        'first':[['cv', 'pork'], ['pork', 'cv']],
        'second':[[34,56],[67,89]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I have tried below two ways of unpacking column values but end up with the AttributeError and ValueError respectively.
How to get the expected output? I dont understand where I am going wrong.

```
df['second'] = df['second'].str.split(',')
```

```
df = df.explode(list("firstsecond"))  #as per explode() documentation
```

Comment: Thanks, well the documentation here:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html is misleading in that case.

Comment: The documentation is not misleading. It says the argument might be a list of columns names. `list("firstsecond")` is not such a list

Answer (score 1):

`list("firstsecond")` produces the list `['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', 's', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd']`.

I believe you are looking for

```
df = df.explode(['first', 'second'], ignore_index=True)
```

which makes `df`

```
     name first second
0  image1    cv     34
1  image1  pork     56
2  image2  pork     67
3  image2    cv     89
```